# Windows 2012 r2 custom image has NTP issue. looses time on reboot

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine, ntp

When i reboot a custom image MS Server 2012 pulls time from the bios and its like 5 hours off. i have ran a cmd to add google time as the ntp and when i resync time it corrects it. once i reboot it loosed the ntp configuration and goes back to local cmos time. i need help either changing bios time or creating a way for the vm to keep the correct ntp time on reboot
i run this and its fixed until next reboot. Thank you Mark

```
W32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time.google.com /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
w32tm /resync
```

Comment: Just a question, is it always the same amount of time that the system is off by? This means it may be an issue with time-zones , if not it may be more serious. You could try looking at this thread as it may have solutions that may work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192450/system-time-becomes-incorrect-on-reboot-of-vms

Comment: Yes t is always the exact amount of time off. it is exactly 5 hours fast. i can change it back and it stays until the vm reboots and it does reboot every night. Thank you Mark