# Change the date to past date on Azure machine

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Azure. I am using Selenium to test applications deployed on Azure VM (Windows server 2019). I have a requirement to change the date to the past date and test some functionality. On other systems, I am using the below command to change the date and it works. However, on azure, it doesn't work.

```
W32TM /unregister
net stop w32time
date 06/27/2020
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change time zone in Azure Virtual Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298337/how-to-change-time-zone-in-azure-virtual-machine). While the title references time zone, if you look at the question and answer (and referenced blog post on MSDN), you will see that they are referring to changing the time and not just the time zone.